# BO2 EOTech Zombie Stopper

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In BO2, for the EOTech reticule, there is an **unlock-able** called the **EOTech Zombie Stopper**.

The requirements for this unlock are

> Get 10 Bloodthirsty medals while aiming down the sights with the EOTech Sight.

Now, the **Bloodthirsty** medal is

> Get 5 kills without dying.

So do I need to simply get 5(x10) kills with at least one kill while aiming down the sights, do I need all 5 kills to be while aiming down the sights or do I need to get 5 kills, hip-firing not even once?

Answer (score 1):

Since Marco seems to have misunderstand the question I'll give my answer:

I believe you have to get 10 times a bloodthirsty with the 5 kills being only kills while aiming down sights. It's like for the skulls camo, if you get a bloodthirsty but 1 kill or more is not with the gun you're unlocking the camo for, it won't count.

But on good thing here is that, for this challenge, I'm pretty sure you can get two guns as primary and secondary, both equipped with an EOTech sight, and get a bloodthirsty using both guns (make sure you ADS at each kill though).

You can verify this very simply : equip a gun with an EOTech sight, look in the barracks how far you are on this challenge, get a bloodthirsty medal with this gun without ADS anytime, and see if your progress in unlocking the reticle increased. If not, it means you should ADS !

Comment: Yup sorry i seem to have misread the question. For the rectacle you 're right, you need to ADS to unlock it.

Comment: If you have any links other than personal experience, feel free to add them ! i couldn't find any myself..

Comment: Ill add some pictures in a few hours when i get home ;)

Comment: Sorry about forgetting to mention 10 medals afterwards. I'll edit it. Thanks for your answer. I'll try it out.